# What is the rightmost point $x_F$ for uniform distribution $X\sim U(0, 1)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The CDF for $X\sim U(0, 1)$ is defined for $X\in R$. Then for the rightmost point $x_F$, is $x_F=1$ or $x_F=\infty$?

Comment: Can you precise what you call the righmost point? Rightmost in which set?

Comment: What is $x_f$ ?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I'm learning the GEV distributions currently. I just found that  the definition for $x_F$ within the field of GEV is: the right endpoint, $x_F$, of a distribution with CDF, $F(·)$, is given by $x_F = sup\{x \in R: F(x) < 1\}.$ So I think the answer below is correct and fits the definition. $x_F$ for $X\sim U(0, 1)$ is 1. Source (at page 5): http://www.columbia.edu/~mh2078/QRM/EVT_MasterSlides.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant domain of a density function is generally its [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)). Given a random variable $X\sim \mathcal{U}(0,1)$, the probability density function is

$$ f_X(x) = \begin{cases}1 & x\in[0,1]\\ 0 & x\notin[0,1] \\ \end{cases} ,$$

and the cumulative distribution function is

$$ F_X(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x < 0 \\ x & x\in[0,1]\\ 1 & x > 1 \\ \end{cases} . $$

The support of $f_X(x)$ is $[0,1]$, and that's where all the interesting stuff is happening. Outside of that range, the density is $0$ everywhere.

The rightmost point that's relevant in any calculations of probabilities is $x=1$. Could you calculate probabilities involving values of $X>1$? Sure, but it's pretty boring, since the PDF is constant at $f_X(x) = 0$ and the CDF is constant at $F_X(x) = 1$.